# Find the Minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^2$, if $ax+by+cz=d$ without using inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the Minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^2$, if $ax+by+cz=d$  without using inequality.

I saw similar question and solution was using inequality and hyper plane and least-norm. I want an elementary method.

Comment: What has your question to do with Number Theory (elementary or otherwise)?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I can not separate number theory from algebra.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ and the plane $ax+by+cz-d=0$. Clearly we have to find the minimum radius of sphere so that it atleast touches the plane.

Intuitively it is easy to deduce that the radius is minimum when  the plane is tangent to the sphere.

$r$=Distance of plane from origin=$|\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}|$

Thus $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=?$

Comment: Fantastic solution :-)

Comment: @Buraian thank you!

Comment: Nice ($+1$). How did you arrive at the idea?

Comment: @BookOfFlames i am currently doing 3d for jee , so it just striked me,

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Oh Nice! Best of Luck for the exam.

Answer (score 2):

I present solution using only elementary algebra.

Let
$\frac{a}{d} = p$,
$\frac{b}{d} = q$ and
$\frac{c}{d} = r$.
So, $px + qy + rz = 1$. We have
$$
(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(p^2 + q^2 + r^2)\geqslant
$$
$$
(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(p^2 + q^2 + r^2) - (px-qy)^2 - (qy - rz)^2 - (px - rz)^2
$$
$$
= (px + qy + rz)^2 =1
$$
Hence,
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geqslant \frac{1}{p^2 + q^2 + r^2}
$$Substitute back $p$, $q$ and $r$.

Comment: clever! you just derived C-S for three terms

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thank! Yes, if I present a solution with algebra, it is impossible to not use inequality. I just showed a little proof to make things look easier.

Comment: Nice solutions, but I wanted algebraic solution without using inequality. Tag (precalculus-algebra ) is for that.

Comment: @sirous Algebraic solution without inequality is not possible I guess, but it is nice to have at least an algebraic solution in hand $\ddot \smile$.

Comment: @BookOfFlames, it is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$ax+by+cz=d$

$A=x^2+y^2+z^2$

Solution: we find z in terms of x and y:

$z=\frac{ax+by-d}{c}$. . . . . . . .(1)

$$A=\frac{(a^2+c^2)x^2+2abxy+(b^2+c^2)y^2-2d(ax+b)y)+d^2}{c^2}$$

Let the numerator of this fraction is N, then we can write:

$N=\frac1{a^2+c^2}[(a^2+c^2)^2x^2+2a(a^2+c^2)(by-d)x]+(b^2+c^2)y^2-2bdy+d^2-
\frac1{a^2+c^2}[(a^2+c^2)x+a(by-d)]^2-\frac{a^2(by-d)^2}{a^2+c^2}+(b^2+c^2)y^2-2bdy+d^2=
\frac1{a^2+c^2}[(a^2+c^2)x+a(by-d)^2+\frac{c^2}{a^2+c^2}[(a^2+b^2+c^2)y^2-2bdy+d^2]$

We also have:

$(a^2+b^2+c^2)y^2-2bdy+d^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2)\big(y-\frac{bd}{a^2+b^2+c^2)}\big)^2+\frac{d^2(a^2+c^2)}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

Therefore:

$$A=x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac{[(a^2+c^2)x+a(by-d)]^2}{c^2(a^2+c^2)}+(a^2+b^2+c^2)\frac{\big(y-\frac{bd}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\big)^2}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{d^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$

A has three positive terms of them first and second terms are not constant and A is minimum when these two terms are equal to 0.So we must have:

$\begin{cases} y=\frac{bd}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\\(a^2+c^2)x+a(by-d)=0 \end{cases}$

Which gives:

$x=\frac{ad}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ and $y=\frac{bd}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ and considering relation (1): $z=\frac{cd}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

With these relations for x, y and z minimum of A is:$\frac{d^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

Comment: Yes, very nice! But if you used inequality, $\frac{[(a^2+c^2)x+a(by-d)]^2}{c^2(a^2+c^2)}+(a^2+b^2+c^2)\frac{\big(y-\frac{bd}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\big)^2}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{d^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2} \geqslant \frac{d^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. The result was direct. Then you just had to prove that the $2$ variable terms could attain the value $0$, and that too could lead to a proof. Your result is of form: The answer + something positive. That is nice but, some extent, tedious as seen. Literally, it is the same.